# Runtime Error when trying to connect to MongoDB using PyMongo in a Flask app from within Docker Container

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask, uwsgi

I have a flask app that connects to MongoDB to serve data.
As soon as the control hits a statement where a connection to MongoDB instance is required, it gives `RuntimeError: can't start new thread` error.

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1251, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1142, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1758, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1703, in __start_session
    self._topology._check_implicit_session_support()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 538, in _check_implicit_session_support
    self._check_session_support()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 554, in _check_session_support
    self._select_servers_loop(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 242, in _select_servers_loop
    self._ensure_opened()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 596, in _ensure_opened
    self._update_servers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 747, in _update_servers
    server.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 49, in open
    self._monitor.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/monitor.py", line 79, in open
    self._executor.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/periodic_executor.py", line 87, in open
    thread.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 957, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

The MongoDB instance is also running within a docker container.
The connection string I am using is like `mongodb://<user>:<password>@192.x.x.x:270xx/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

I am able to connect to the same Mongo instance from a Python Shell running on Host System but not from within the Flask App running in Docker.

Also, I ran the following command to get number of PIDs against that container 
`docker stats  --no-stream --format '{{.PIDs}}\t{{.Name}}'`

and it returns

```
PIDs    Name
1       flask-app
```

I have monitored resource usage on the host and it is negligible. I am hardly using 10% or RAM/CPU at any given time.
I have also tried stopping all containers but the FlaskApp and MongoDB and it would still return the same error.